# How to substract a value from each row in a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell

I have a **cell** with **dimension 41X41** as shown below

[image]

that has values equal to **1**, it means **all its values are equal to ones** as shown below:

[image]

Based on many values, I could not include it here in one figure, but its dimension is 41 x 41.

What I was trying to do is **calculate the number of ones in each row minus one** as shown in the snippet of line code below:

```
ccc = sum(isSmaller{cc,:} == 1)-1
```

**In order to get a cell with 1 row with 40 columns dimension that has 40s**. as shown below:

[image]

My problem is instead of 40 columns is still showing 41 columns after deleting one from each row as indicated below.

[image]

May I get assistance, please? I need it to be 1 row with 40 columns.

Note: I do not care for the first 40 rows or columns or the lasts or the middle ones. I just need it to be done by itself only by minus one.
[image]
After that, I need to sum all the 40s in this ccc = 1x40.

Below is my try:

```
for cc = 1:length(isSmaller)
    ccc = sum(isSmaller{cc,:} == 1)-1
end
```

Comment: No idea what you mean by "Note: I do not care for the first 40 rows or columns or the lasts or the middle ones. I just need it to be done by itself only by minus one."? What is "it"? Maybe provide a more representative example (with a smaller matrix) for what you actual case is?

Comment: Also, to make sure, when you say "subtract a value" do you mean mathematical subtraction? Or do you possibly mean "remove" or "trim" a value so that it is not included in subsequent calculations?

Comment: @horchler, I re-edited the post with a figure. I just need to remove (1) after each summation to the number of ones in each row, but without determining its location, i.e., I do not need to select which row or column.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `isSmaller` is a 1-by-1 cell array whose single cell contains a 41-by-41 matrix of logical values all equal to `1` (`true`):

```
isSmaller={true(41)};
```

Then you wish to calculate the sum of each row of this matrix inside of a cell and subtract one from the result:

```
sum(isSmaller{1},1)-1
```

But since you only care about the first 40 rows you can trim off the last row with:

```
sum(isSmaller{1}(:,1:40),1)-1
```

Or:

```
sum(isSmaller{1}(:,1:end-1),1)-1
```

This returns a 1-by-40 matrix where each element is `40`.

Finally, you want to sum over the 40 elements of this matrix:

```
sum(sum(isSmaller{1}(:,1:end-1),1)-1)
```

This returns `1600`, as expected.

No `for` loops are needed if this is all you need to do and your example is representative. I urge you to read through Matlab's documentation on [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), in particular on [how to access data within them](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: No dear sir, I do not care for the first 40 rows. This is because the cell will have zeros and ones later. Maybe later the last row will be ones and the row before the end zeros; in this case, I will lose a row with ones. I want to calculate the number of ones in each row, but by minus one, without specifying which row or column, the results will be a cell 1x40, all its values 40s.

Comment: Please then update your question with an example that is representative of the problem you're trying to solve. We can't guess at things you don't share.

Comment: Also, it's really unclear, in this question and other you have posted, why you are using cell arrays at all.

Comment: The post has been updated, dear sir.